# how to build a basic jquery rss feed

Tags: jquery, mysql, rss

i would like know how to build a rss feed that is evergoing using jquery.

additionally, i would like to use php and mysql to put the feeds into a table to be re-used and searched.

thanks so much =)

Comment: And your question is what exactly? ... Go read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: how to create a rss feed with php, mysql, and jquery to display them

Comment: @bzupnick, that's not a specific problem. You are asking for a fully working software solution.

Comment: @bzupnick, there are tons of those if you search Google. I found [this](http://www.script-tutorials.com/import-rss-feeds-using-jfeed-jquery/) and many others on the first page after searching for `jquery+rss`

Comment: i dont see why you need javascript to BUILD an rss feed... maybe you want to SHOW an rss feed? and even so, why you need javascript for that?

Comment: fine, let me be more specific. i need to learn how to make a script using php and mysql to grab, and input rss feeds into a database. forget the javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what that (what you asked in the comments), you'll need to download the rss. It could be done using [file_get_contents](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Once you've downloaded it, you'll need to parse the xml using an XML parser (obviously). There's [SimpleXml](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or [Dom](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). Actually there are several xml parsers, i wouldn't be surprised if you find a parser created specifically for rss. If you use SimpleXml you could directly download the rss from the constructor and you wont need to do it yourself.

Finally all you need to do is loop through the entries of the rss and save them in a database.

So you see, you don't need javascript to do this =)

Good Luck